# Is possible to avoid the ASP.NET Core SignalR handshake protocol message to start a connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

In ASP.NET Core SignalR, when a WebSockets connection is started, one needs to send an initial message containing `{ "protocol": "json", "version": 1 }`.

Is this avoidable? Any chance to start a connection without the protocol handshake?

I've found myself in an scenario where I need to integrate some SignalR Core into an API Gateway, and this API Gateway won't be able to automatically send the protocol handshake message.

Comment: Added a tag so maybe @davidfowl wil see this

Comment: @JHBonarius Thank you ;-) Anyway it seems like there's no chance to set a default protocol and make optional the protocol message exchange... https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/docs/specs/HubProtocol.md --> `After opening a connection to the server the client must send a HandshakeRequest message to the server as its first message. The handshake message is always a JSON message and contains the name of the format (protocol) as well as the version of the protocol that will be used for the duration of the connection.` They say literally *MUST* :-(

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether the gateway needs to be a client of the hub. I.e. - does it need to receive push notifications itself?

If it only needs to be able to invoke push notifications and not receive them, then you could define a standard API in the same project as the hub. The gateway could call methods on that, and those methods would invoke the methods on the hub.

If the gateway itself does need to receive push notifications then I don't see how it could do so without connecting to the hub.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It's the second case (https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/websockets/). Backend needs to send messages to the gateway through a WebSockets channel.

Comment: Anyway my question is about the ability to connect to a hub without SignalR's protocol handshake.